# Why won't my button disable itself?

Tags: java, if-statement, jbutton

I am writing code for a slot machine and my `btnRespin` won't disable itself if `btnHold1` is disabled, `btnHold2` is disabled and then if `btnRespin` is pressed.

**Here's what I have:**

```
if (btnHold1.isEnabled()==false && btnHold2.isEnabled()==false)
{
      counter = 0;
      counter2 = 0;
      timer1.stop();
      timer2.stop();
      btnHold1.setEnabled(false);
      btnHold2.setEnabled(false);
}
else if (btnHold1.isEnabled()==false && btnHold2.isEnabled()==false && event.getSource()==btnRespin)
{
      counter = 0;
      counter2 = 0;
      timer1.stop();
      timer2.stop();
      counter3 = 0;
      timer3.start();
      btnHold3.setEnabled(false);
      btnRespin.setEnabled(false);

}
```

Comment: Would be interesting to see the part before the else if

Comment: @NineBerry
if (btnHold1.isEnabled()==false && btnHold2.isEnabled()==false)
   {
    counter = 0;
    counter2 = 0;
    timer1.stop();
    timer2.stop();
    btnHold1.setEnabled(false);
    btnHold2.setEnabled(false);
   }

Answer (score 1):

When both buttons are disabled, then the condition of the first if is true, this way the condition of the second if will never be evaluated.

Simply use two separate ifs instead of the if else:

```
if (btnHold1.isEnabled()==false && btnHold2.isEnabled()==false)
{
      counter = 0;
      counter2 = 0;
      timer1.stop();
      timer2.stop();
      btnHold1.setEnabled(false);
      btnHold2.setEnabled(false);
}


if (btnHold1.isEnabled()==false && btnHold2.isEnabled()==false && event.getSource()==btnRespin)
{
      counter = 0;
      counter2 = 0;
      timer1.stop();
      timer2.stop();
      counter3 = 0;
      timer3.start();
      btnHold3.setEnabled(false);
      btnRespin.setEnabled(false);

}
```

However, this code still doesn't make much sense. Why would you want to disable btnHold1 and btnHold2 when they are already both disabled? And

Comment: This does work and disables the Respin button however, timer3 doesnt start once the respin button is pressed before it disables itself

Comment: How do you know that? I suppose you have some other code in that function that disables timer3. You just need to make a good plan of your logic and then implement that logic.

Answer (score 1):

Your `else if` statement is more specific than your `if` statement. Both check for if `btnHold1` and `btnHold2` are disabled so it will always go into your `if` statement before your `else if`.

Try swapping your conditions so:

```
if (btnHold1.isEnabled()==false && btnHold2.isEnabled()==false && event.getSource()==btnRespin)
{
      counter = 0;
      counter2 = 0;
      timer1.stop();
      timer2.stop();
      counter3 = 0;
      timer3.start();
      btnHold3.setEnabled(false);
      btnRespin.setEnabled(false);
}


else if (btnHold1.isEnabled()==false && btnHold2.isEnabled()==false)
{
      counter = 0;
      counter2 = 0;
      timer1.stop();
      timer2.stop();
      btnHold1.setEnabled(false);
      btnHold2.setEnabled(false);    
  }
```